# Eclipse Liberty plugin keystore feature editor

Tags: websphere-liberty

This is a heads-up, not a question:

I am using Eclipse Neon with latest WAS Liberty Plugin and when I add keystore to the server.xml using built-in config editor for Liberty, the password is not designated as mandatory field (see pic below - there is no "*" to indicate mandatory field), yet when I skip it and start a server I get an error: `[ERROR   ] CWPKI0808E: A password of at least 6 characters is required to create the default keystore. The default keystore is not created.`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases where a password is not required, hence it is optional. In your case the keyStore will be created with the personal certificate which needs to be protected. We will try to clarify this more.